# How can i create a session in Android?

Tags: android

I'm building an app with a Login area. I'm using PHP to insert the Values from my Application into my database, I'm using parameters.

I would like to get the information from the user, when he logs in, so, i already got the the ID from the user, and I would like to put the ID inside a variable, and create a session to call everytime that the user visits his profile.

The user will do the Login inside the Mainactivity

**Mainactivity**

```
public void login(View view){
    String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
    new SigninActivity(this,status,role,0).execute(username,password);

 }

class Session {
            public String username = "I WILL PUT THE USERNAME OR ID HERE";
        }

     class App extends Application {
            Session session = new Session();

            public String getUsername() {
                return session.username;
            }

            public void setUsername(String username) {
                session.username = username;

            }
        }
```

And now, I'm trying to call the string username in other activity named test.

**test**

```
public class test extends Activity{
    private TextView get;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teste);
        get = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.get);

        App app = (App) getApplication();
        String username = app.getUsername();

        if (username.equals("")) {
            // the user is not logged in, do something
        }
    }

}
```

I inserted that in android manifest

```
    <activity
    android:name=".test"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But when i open the test activity i receive multiple errors. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Show the stack trace

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VR9YGHS.png

Comment: [Duplicated Question] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678669/how-to-maintain-session-in-android

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicated Question] [How to maintain session in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678669/how-to-maintain-session-in-android)

you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or you can store it in the [database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Comment: The question is duplicated, but i still not knowing why i'm getting error