# Best way of maintaining a session in an android app after singing in?

Tags: java, android, session

I am making an app where as soon as you sign in, it will query into the database and retrieve your details, but what's the best way of storing these details as i change between activities without having to repeatedly query into the database again to retrieve them ?

I have tried using the `intent.putExtra()` method but it's causes `NullPointerExceptions` when i return to previous activities. Also `putExtra()` will not work on one of my classes which is `HostApduService`.

So what's the best method to maintian a session ? Will i need to use cookies or something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain session in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678669/how-to-maintain-session-in-android)

Comment: you can store all the details in SharedPreferences, so that you can access those data from any activity

Comment: You can use this library to remove boilerplate code of sharedpreferences. https://github.com/moinkhan-in/PreferenceSpider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` is what you are looking for.

> A `SharedPreferences` object points to a file containing *key-value* pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them. Each `SharedPreferences` file is managed by the framework and can be private or shared.

---

**How to use it:**

**Read data:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int value = sharedPref.getString("my_value_key", "default_value");
```

**Write data:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPref.edit().putString("my_value_key", "my_value").apply();
```

---

You can read more about `SharedPreferences` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Good luck. :)