# keeps the user login in android studio

Tags: android, database

I am connected to an online database and I have a login form.
How to let the user logged in even if he gets out of the application?
**More details:**
First, the user will log in into the application and then he will close it.
When he gets back to the application I want him to be logged in automatically without asking for username and password even if the phone is not connected to the internet. But when he logs out, it will re-ask him for username and password.
*Thanks.*

Comment: I think there are many different ways to get this done (local db, SharedPreferences etc.). But: please don't store the password as plain text somewhere in your app, use a flag or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Can you give me more details such as examples or tutorial links or videos?

Comment: You can find a detailed answer to this on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678669/how-to-maintain-session-in-android).

Comment: You can do this by saving user id in SharedPreferences. And in onCreate()  onResume() method you check if user id is present in SharedPreferences or not. And when user logs out you just remove user id from SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

you can use sharedpreferences to check if the user already logged in:

```
    Boolean isLoggedIn  = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Is_LogIn", false);//default value false

    if (isLoggedIn){
        //redirect user to home page

    }else{
        //ask for login credentials

    }
```